# Changing app.servlet.version does not affect web.xml

Tags: grails, servlets, web.xml

Is there an issue to set the `app.servlet.version` to `3.0` in the `application.properties` for grails 2.0?

I created a new app, added the line `app.servlet.version=3.0` to the `application.properties` and executed `grails war` (even tried `clean` before). However the web.xml still starts with:

```
<web-app         xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" 
               version="2.5" 
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" 
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
```

Iwould have expected to see 3.0. I also tried this Procedere with `2.4` and it is still `2.5`. Is it the wrong place, which I am looking at?

Comment: there are a couple of related bugs. Perhaps it's another one?

Comment: alright, thx. i thought, that i do something wrong. I will raise a ticket then.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like, that you need to change the `BuildConfig.groovy` as well, in order to achieve servlet version 3.0 in your `web.xml`. Add the following line into a plain grails project and the web.xml will start with desired version 3.0:

```
grails.servlet.version = "3.0"
```