# Grails app.servlet.version OR grails.servlet.version?

Tags: servlets, grails, web.xml

Do I need to configure both app.servlet.version ***and*** grails.servlet.version?

The former is in application.properties and the latter in BuildConfig.groovy

Better safe than sorry? I just don't like redundancy.

See related:

- [Changing app.servlet.version does not affect web.xml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8615596/changing-app-servlet-version-does-not-affect-web-xml)

Comment: I have so many Grails plugins across many teams. I'm really not looking forward to keeping all these in sync. Anyone else have a bunch of plugins to maintain?

Answer (score 0):

It would seem like you do not need to have or set an entry in application.properties IF there is an entry in your BuildConfig.groovy file.

To confirm this I looked in the grails war file creator (GrailsProjectWarCreator.groovy) code and saw that it does indeed use the apps BuildConfig setting to populate the application.properties file when building the war.